# Examples of (use of) position-systems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As you now, the most used number system is the position system with base 10, where for instance $101$ means $1\cdot 10^2+0\cdot 10^1 + 1 \cdot 10^0$.  Likewise we can define binary number system with base 2, ternary number system with base 3, and so on.

But we can also define non-standard number systems with a position-dependent base (mixed radix), as an example a 2,3,2-system, where we have
$$ \begin{alignat}        
 0   &= 0_2 0_30_2  &= 0\cdot 2^0 \\
 1   &= 0_2 0_3 1_2     &= 1\cdot 2^0 \\
 2   &= 0_2 1_3 0_2   &= 0\cdot 2^0 + 1 \cdot 2 \\
 3   &= 0_2 1_3 1_2   &= 1\cdot 2^0 + 1\cdot 2 \\
 4   &= 0_2 2_3 0_2   &= 0\cdot 2^0 + 2\cdot 2 \\
 5   &= 0_2 2_3 1_2   &= 1\cdot 2^0 + 2\cdot 2 \\
 6   &= 1_2 0_3 0_2   &= 0\cdot 2^0 + 0\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 3\cdot 2 \\
 7    &= 1_2 0_3 1_2  &= 1\cdot 2^0 + 0\cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 3  \cdot 2  \\
 8    &= 1_2 1_3 0_2  &= 0\cdot 2^0 + 1\cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 3  \cdot 2   \\
 9   &=  1_2 1_3 1_2  &= 1\cdot 2^0 + 1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 3  \cdot 2   \\  
 10  &=  1_2 2_3 0_2  &= 0\cdot 2^0 + 2 \cdot 2 + 1\cdot 3 \cdot 6
\end{alignat}$$
and so on.  Such mixed-radix systems seems unnatural at first sight, but are not:
whenever, in a computer program we use a large array with multiple dimensions, such as an array with dimensions [12,8,5,7] we are implicitely using a mixed-radix number. Other examples are calendar and timekeeping.

So then to the question: I want a (large) list of uses of such mixed-radix numbers, and better yet, list of uses of even other, stranger, non-standard systems for writing numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure if the tag is correct!! anybody can do better?  also, should be community-wiki

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, some people counted money in pounds, shillings, and pence. I have forgotten what the ratios were, something like 12 and 20.